# Graphite skips and cuts off the metric names when importing a bunch of data

Tags: graphite

Has anybody met such a strange graphite behavior when it skips and cuts off some metrics and metric names?

For example, when I import a file which is about ~20Mb with the command

```
cat ./metrics.log | nc graphite-host 2003
```

that contains the data like this

```
...
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.min 0.0000 1353400609
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.max 0.0000 1353400609
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.arithmetic_mean 0.0000 1353400609
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.geometric_mean 0.0000 1353400609
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.harmonic_mean 0.0000 1353400609
pkd.zont_10_4_8_107.histogram.ibgm_fx_import.failure.lifetime.median 0.0000 1353400609
...
```

some metric names become invalid and even not all the metrics from the file are imported.

[image: invalid metric name]

As you can see the metric `zont_10_4_8_107` is displayed as `nt_10_4_8_107`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. The problem is solved. The file with metrics was corrupted.